# R: using `rnorm` to create vectors with specific variance

Tags: r

I want to create two different vectors of data which are normal distributions. One which has a a mean value of 0 and variance of 1; one which has a mean value of 0 and variance of 0.25.

Can this be done with `rnorm`? If not what is the best way to do this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. Type `?rnorm` into the console to learn more about it. I'm assuming you want vectors with 100 numbers, but just change `n` if you want.

```
vector1 = rnorm(n = 100, mean = 0, sd = sqrt(1))
vector2 = rnorm(n = 100, mean = 0, sd = sqrt(0.25))
```

Comment: Sorry this is so ridiculously obvious now. I just couldn't understand why you could only set the mean and the SD but nor the var.

Comment: No problem. We all have those moments :)

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do it with `rnorm()`

first vector( of 1000 elements) with mean = 0 and variance = 1( std.dev = 1)

```
a = rnorm(1000, mean = 0, sd = 1)
```

second vector ( of 1000 elements) with mean = 0 and variance = 0.25( std.dev = 0.5)

```
b = rnorm(1000, mean = 0, sd = 0.5)
```